# How to position footer between 2 divs?

Tags: html, css

So I'm just playing around and trying to create a 3 column layout. I'm having trouble making the footer go between these 2 divs sidebars at the bottom. Basically my middle column doesn't go all the way down like my side bars, my middle column cuts off so I can place the footer right below it and it lines up with my sidebars. Margin-left is something I know I can do but I don't want to do that because i believe there's a better way.

[image: What I have so far]

Here's what I have so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>First</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header></header>

    <div id="first-column"></div>

    <div id="middle-column"></div>

    <div id="third-column"></div>

    <footer></footer>

</body>
</html>
```

**css**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: #444444;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

#first-column {
    width: 15%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    float: left;
}

#middle-column {
    width: 70%;
    height: 70%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

#third-column {
    width: 15%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    float: left;
}

footer {
    background-color: #222222;
    height: 10%;
    width: 70%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a number of ways to solve this. the most basic change you can do to  make this layout work:

your left col's `width` is set to `15%`. if you change the footer's `margin-left` from `100px` to `15%`, they will all be lined up.

https://jsfiddle.net/7ufL979v/

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `margin-left` as you mention, you can float the third column to the right instead and you'll be able to float your footer like the other boxes (if you also remove `position: absolute` and `margin-left`).

```
#third-column {
    width: 15%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: #d8d8d8;
    float: right;
}

footer {
    background-color: #222222;
    height: 10%;
    width: 70%;
    bottom: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

You may also want to look into [using flexbox](http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html), which is a more modern way to solve this, and is actually built to produce layout, unlike floating boxes left and right.

Answer (score 0):

you could simply put it into the middle column, at the very bottom.